# Changing the rowsource of a combo box based on another combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a forms `frmDatasheet` and `frmComboHolder` contained in `NavigationSubform`. 
`frmDatasheet` is bound to table `tblBuilding`. 
Form `frmComboHolder` contains the two combo boxes.

The combo boxes are used to filter records to make the database more user friendly.

I want to change the `rowSoruce` of `combo2` based on the filtered results displayed on `frmDatasheet`.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim Qry1 As String As String
Dim Qry2 As String String

Qry1 = "SELECT DISTINCT Room FROM tblBuilding WHERE Room IS NOT NULL"
Qry2 = "SELECT DISTINCT TenancyCode FROM tblBuilding WHERE TenancyCode IS 
NOT NULL"

With Me.cobo1
Me.combo1.RowSource = Qry1
End With

With Me.combo2
Me.combo2.RowSource = Qry2
End With

End Sub


Private Sub cobo1_AfterUpdate()

Dim Qry3 As String
Dim Qry4 As String

Qry3 = "SELECT * FROM tblBuilding WHERE Room = combo1.Value  ORDER BY 
ItemName ASC"

With Me.Combo1
Me.frmDatasheet.Form.RecordSource = Qry3

Me.combo2.RowSourse = "SELECT DISTINCT TenancyCode FROM [Qry3] WHERE 
TenancyCode IS NOT NULL" 

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concatenate the value:

```vb
Qry3 = "SELECT DISTINCT TenancyCode, Room FROM tblBuilding WHERE Room = " & combo1.Value & " ORDER BY 
ItemName ASC"
```

or, if value is text:

```vb
Qry3 = "SELECT DISTINCT TenancyCode, Room FROM tblBuilding WHERE Room = '" & combo1.Value & "' ORDER BY 
ItemName ASC"
```

Comment: I tried that. But I get an error saying the record source does not exist. I though it would be assigned by the line: `Me.frmDatasheet.Form.RecordSource = Qry3`

Comment: If I change`Qry3 = "SELECT * FROM tblBuilding WHERE Room = '" & combo1.Value & "' ORDER BY 
ItemName ASC"` To `Qry3 = "SELECT DISTINCT, TenancyCode, Room FROM tblBuilding WHERE Room = '" & combo1.Value & "' ORDER BY 
ItemName ASC"` Works as expected. Cheers

Comment: OK, though I doubt you have the comma after DISTINCT. Also, please mark as answered if you feel so.